# Trying to add the values in a list in python using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
    id        POSTINGS  
     1     [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
     2     [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
     3     [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
     4     [9,1,2,0,0,0,0,0]
     5     [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
     6     [9,9,9,9,9,8,9,9]
     7     [9,9,9,9,9,9,8,9]
     8     [9,9,9,9,8,8,9,9]
```

Here i am trying to add a list of values in POSTING column and store the result in a new "SUM" column

Expected output

```
     id        POSTINGS               SUM
     1     [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]           56
     2     [9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8]           54
     3     [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]            9
     4     [9,1,2,0,0,0,0,0]           12
     5     [9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]           56
     6     [9,9,9,9,9,8,9,9]           55
     7     [9,9,9,9,9,9,8,9]           55
     8     [9,9,9,9,8,8,9,9]           54
```

Comment: Is this `R` or Python?

Comment: @giantslovedeathmetal in python

Comment: Are you using Pandas?

Comment: Yes @GiantsLoveDeathMetal

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Comment: How exactly are your data organized? As a Pandas dataframe, a bunch of lists, ... ?

Comment: @user8545255 let me know if my answer worked.

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Thank you..its working

Comment: @user8545255 don't forget to tick the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sum` function in `apply` and you'll get a column containing the sum of the list in `POSTINGS`:

```
df['SUM'] = df['POSTINGS'].apply(sum)
```